# Swashbuckle.AspNet.Core: AddSwaggerGen() not present/found

Tags: swashbuckle.aspnetcore

After I added the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package to my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project, I'm not able to call the `AddSwaggerGen` function.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are chaining on the "AddControllers()".

Try:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen();
```